# Trouble listing a Git repository using SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I'm having trouble listing a Git repository using SSH.

```
$ git ls-remote -h ssh://<user>@<server.com>/repos/GitTest
```

This command returns the following error:

```
fatal: ''/repos/GitTest'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, if I run the same command against the same repository via Windows shared UNC path, it works fine, see below:

```
$ git ls-remote -h //<server.com>/Users/<user>/repos/GitTest

b2f52213aac6e8c178c96860d96ad7da06733ddf        refs/heads/master
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are using SSH, do you have the right privilege for that repo?

Comment: Yes, the user I am authenticating as has full Windows permissions to the SSH server's home directory.

Comment: Sorry for mis-looked at the error log. I think this due to the error of SSH URL format.

Comment: I always start problems like this by taking Git out of the picture entirely: make sure `ssh user@host ls repos` works, for instance. (If the server is Windows, replace `ls repos` with whatever the Windows equivalent might be.)

Comment: @torek Thank you for that recommendation.  I am able to connect successfully and list the contents of the directory.     ssh <user>@<server.com> dir repos

Comment: OK, the next step would be to make sure that the command `git ls-remote` runs on the server, actually runs on the server.  That's `git upload-pack`: `ssh user@host git upload-pack repos/GitTest` (the output is semi-readable, you can feed it an EOF after getting the `0000` line). The output should begin with, e.g., `00f211ae6ca18f6325c858f1e3ea2b7e6a045666336d HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.14.1`

Comment: This is what I got.  00fcb2f52213aac6e8c178c96860d96ad7da06733ddf HEADmulti_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master agent=git/2.17.1.windows.2
003fb2f52213aac6e8c178c96860d96ad7da06733ddf refs/heads/master
0000

Comment: OK - this verifies that the command-line ssh works. So your Git must be using some *other* ssh or invoking ssh incorrectly. The next step is `GIT_TRACE=1 git ls-remote ...` which will show you how Git is trying to invoke ssh.

Comment: $ GIT_TRACE=1 git ls-remote -h <user>@<server.com>:repos/GitTest.git
09:46:22.464378 exec_cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
09:46:22.491240 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git ls-remote -h <user>@<server.com>:repos/GitTest.git
09:46:22.506282 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh <user>@<server.com> 'git-upload-pack '\''repos/GitTest.git'\'''
<user>@<server.com>'s password:
fatal: ''repos/GitTest.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by @GenoChen, this is only due to a syntax error with the URL itself (the separator between the SSH domain name and the path should be `:`, not `/`).

Could you try this instead?

```
git ls-remote -h <user>@<server.com>:repos/GitTest
```

For the record, the different kinds of URLs accepted by Git are described in the [Git URLs section of the doc of git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a).

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input thus far! Unfortunately, the problem persists:

Comment: $ git ls-remote <user>@<server.com>:repos/GitTest
<user>@<server.com>'s password:
fatal: ''repos/GitTest'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: OK... so I suspect this is now a path issue. Maybe `git ls-remote -h <user>@<server.com>:repos/GitTest/.git` should be OK... otherwise do `ssh user@server.com` and double-check the absolute path of the .git repo...

Comment: `:` is a separator only in scp-like URLs. In `ssh://` URLs the separator is `/`: `ssh://[user@]host.xz/path/to/repo`